# Transferring data from Excel to dataGridView

Tags: c#, excel

I have a problem when I want to transfer data from Excel to dataGridView in C#.

My Excel's column has numeric and alphanumeric values. But for example, if the column has 3 numbers and 2 alphanumeric values then only the numbers are shown in the dataGridView, and vice versa. Why aren't all the values shown? The next is what happen:

```
Excel's Column:                   DataGridView's Column:
   45654                               45654
   P745K 
   31233                               31233
   23111                               23111
   45X2Y
```

Here is my code to load the dataGridView:

```
string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\test.xls;Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;""";

DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.OleDb");

DbDataAdapter adapter = factory.CreateDataAdapter();

DbCommand selectCommand = factory.CreateCommand();
selectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [sheet1$]";

DbConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection();
connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;

selectCommand.Connection = connection;

adapter.SelectCommand = selectCommand;

data = new DataSet();

adapter.Fill(data);

dataGridView1.DataSource = data.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just add "IMEX=1" into your connection string like ↓

```
string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\test.xls;Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1""";
```

It would forceably read all values in as strings .

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting all the cells as text in the excel sheet before importing.  (Which you could do manually or programatically)